# Inkscape makes the text between $ $ white in pdf_tex

Tags: pdftex, inkscape

When I use Inkscape to produce a pdf_tex file, in the final pdf, normal text appears with the right color but any text in LaTeX (i.e. between $ $) appears in white (making it invisible). Is there a way to fix this, without manually changing the colors of every instance of LaTeX text in my pdf_tex file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to provide a [compilable test document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix. Please also provide some information about the operating system and TeX distribution you employ, including when you last updated it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP's issue was resolved using information not made advailable in the initial posting.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Inkscape after deleting it's config files in Ubuntu resolved this issue.